# Android Virtual Device does not display correctly

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRQND.png)

please see the pic. How can I fix this error? I tried installing a couple other devices, checked some function for hardware vs software graphics. TIA

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="haroonahmad.berkeleysucksapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Berkeley Admisions"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="88dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="88dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="335dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="268dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="335dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Points: 0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="415dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

</RelativeLayout>
```

edit: sorry i'm a completely new to adding code, didn't realize I could only add to the first post.

I tried changing the ConstraintLayout in both places to RelativeLayout, didn't work. then tried right clicking on the resource file and changed the layout and layoutvertical to RelativeLayout, and still didn't work. thanks for any further suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a root layout that does not match the alignments you're setting in other views. Try using RelativeLayout as root layout.

Maybe if you post your XML layout, it is easier for us to identify the problem.

Comment: Please see the OP now with some updates based on your suggestion. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed it by changing the whole text before xmlns to RelativeLayout. thanks for the tip!